# Fixed-width text not appearing correctly in Safari after Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, safari, font

I recently updated to Lion, and have found that at least some HTML tagged as <pre> or <tt> shows up looking like this

[image]

I've tried changing the fixed-width font in Safari. I've tried rebooting. The same page looks fine in Chrome, and when I copy the text in question out of Safari into BBedit, it looks fine. I'm at a bit of a loss.

Comment: I've embedded your picture and removed the "thanks in advance" people will see you offered it and we generally don't sign off / prepend a "dear readers" here in the interest of signal to noise. We vote to thank people for good questions, comments and answers :-)

Comment: As to the problem - this usually happens when a font is disabled in Font Book - can you add a comment or edit the question to show this on a site we all can go to  - that would let us tell you which fonts to look for in Font Book.

Comment: bmike: Macintouch.com as an example. There's a string of spaces wrapped in a &lt;pre> tag below the header that appears as those placeholder characters. I'm currently using FontCase for font management, fwiw, but this is a problem when using Courier (which is a system font, of course) as the fixed-width font. Interestingly, I can view source on macintouch.com and view that normally in Safari, but when I load the the css file for it, that also appears as placeholders.

Comment: Excellent - a safe boot (hold the shift when powering on the mac) will rebuild the font database / caches so that might be a great place to start troubleshooting. This is typical find corruption where another app substitutes / defaults to a font without issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15808306#15808306):

> Restart in [safe mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564) than normal boot. If that doesn't do the trick, run Font Book and validate all fonts.

Comment: Clearing the font cache seems to have done the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a known bug.** This problem is often because of a bug with Safari 5.1 that appears when you are also using professional font management programs like [Linotype FontExplorer](http://www.fontexplorerx.com/) and [Extensis Suitcase Fusion](http://www.extensis.com/en/products/suitcasefusion3/overview.jsp).

Disable you font management program, clean your font cache, reboot, and check with the company that makes your font management program and see if they have a new update to address working around this new bug.